# Chromium "New Tab" page not loading

Tags: 20.04, chromium

Chromium "New Tab" page stays blank. No search bar, no icons, nothing. When it happened for the first time, it showed a error message on the screen. But now it stays completely blank. Browsing works completely fine. No problem with the internet connection.

My Chromium version : `88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)`
Ubuntu version : `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64`

When I opened up the console on the new tab page it showed two errors.

```
GET chrome://new-tab-page/modules/dummy/foo_proxy.js net::ERR_FAILED
GET chrome://new-tab-page/modules/dummy/module.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Yes it does. Same answer has been given here too. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by disabling this flag `chrome://flags/#ntp-webui` (Use the WebUI new tab page when opening a new tab). Checked on  chromium version 88.0.4324.96.

It is possible that in the next releases the *WebUI* functionality will be restored.

Comment: Good to know. Sounds like a regression in a recent Chrome.